# Getting Exception in thread "main" Error

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I have array with those numbers and my task is to make 2 new arrays where one array(poz) will have all positive numbers from array and second array(neg) will take all negative values out of array

```
public class obNiza {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
     Arrays.sort(array);

     int[] poz= new int[6];
     int[] neg= new int[5];

     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     { 
         if(array[i] < 0)
             poz[i] = array[i];
         else neg[i] = array[i];
     }

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(poz));
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(neg));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are poz and neg arrays randomly sized? Where did 5 and 6 come from?

Comment: `poz[i]` and `neg[i]` wont exists for `i>4` or `i>5` as this will be out of bound

Comment: Also `array[i] < 0` is not a positive number

Comment: @Stultuske the `array` has a greater size than either of the other arrays. By using `i` to loop over the `array` he´ll exceed the limit of the other two arrays he tries to store the negative and positive values at, because he does use `i` aswell here to access the index of these arrays.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy So what size do i put in int[] poz= new int[]; so it does the job i am kinda confused as a begginer      int[] neg= new int[];

Comment: For completeness I would add the exception text to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't know in advance the amount of positive and negative numbers, you're better off using an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> poz = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> neg = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then loop through and add to the relevant `ArrayList` as needed

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > 0) {
                poz.add(array[i]);
            } else {
                neg.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
```

Note: change `array[i] > 0` to `array[i] >= 0` if you want 0s to go into `poz`

**Output:**

> [12, 12, 23, 43, 43, 545]
>
> [-999, -87, -55, -22, -4, 0, 0]

Comment: Alright this is doing job a need just a few more lines, how do i apply systemoutprintln in this code since sout (poz); doesnt work

Comment: `System.out.println(poz);` and `System.out.println(neg);` will print them as in the box above. https://ideone.com/omLmvO

Comment: it does work thank you so much, also i have 1 little thing what should can i do about those 2  0,0 in neg output since i dont need zeroes in my final output

Comment: There are a few ways; one would be to change the `else` to `else if (array[i] < 0)`

Comment: thats working flawless awesome, my teacher accepted it but told me i need new array that will have duplicates from array and write them[+ how many duplicates it does have] sorry for bothering u so much..

Comment: @MihajloSljukic Can you explain that again? You want a third `array` containing any duplicates from `poz` or `neg`

Comment: I need third array that contains all duplicates from this array  int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87}; *0 is counted in as well* and and how many duplicates does it have for example (12=2)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you could use `List` (`ArrayList`):

```
import java.util.*;

public class ObNiza {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
    Arrays.sort(array);

    List<Integer> positivesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> negativesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) { 
        if (array[i]==0) { // since 0 is not negative nor positive 
            continue;
        }
        if(array[i] < 0) {
            positivesList.add(array[i]);
        } else {
            negativesList.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    Integer[] poz = positivesList.toArray(new Integer[positivesList.size()]);
    Integer[] neg = negativesList.toArray(new Integer[negativesList.size()]);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(poz));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(neg));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` size is 13. But `poz` array's size + `neg` array's size = 13. In for loop the zero values in `array`, added to `neg` array. Because of this throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You must delete zero values in `array`. Because zero is neither positive nor negative.

To delete a value from an array you can use `ArrayUtils` class.

For example:
`array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)`

[commons.apache.org library:Javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)